# Сравнение двумерных массивов разного размера (шинглов)

Tags: массивы, delphi

Пытаюсь сравнить 2 текста между собой. 
Провел канонизацию. Выделил шинглы. Нашел хэши шинглов. Записал хэши в два динамических двумерных массива типа `Integer`. Нужно найти процент совпадений. Проблема в том, что размер массивов может быть разный. И, вообще, как их сравнивать?
Например, первый массив `[0..9,0..3]`, а второй `[0..9,0..5]`

Comment: вы у нас спрашиваете алгоритм сравнения, который вам нужен? или в чем вопрос?

Comment: да, алгоритм сравнения. Мне кажется, что простой перебор элементов массивов не устроит или устроит?

Comment: Устроит или нет, это вас надо спросить :) Что вы от сравнения хотите то? узнать что они полностью совпадают/не совпадают, или еще какие то варианты? Что за принцип сравнения вам нужен? Если длины массивов разные, то можно уже не перебирать ничего? или надо?  Если надо сравнить два массива на точное соответствие, то вам поможет [`CompareMem()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.CompareMem). Поэтому я и прошу вас написать, алгоритм (в смысле принцип) сравнения массивов.

Comment: Что за процент совпадений? Это процент точно совпавших массивов 2го уровня,  или процент совпавших элементов?

Comment: Я хочу узнать какой алгоритм сравнения мне подойдет для сравнения. CompareMem не подходит, так как он отвечает только на один вопрос, одинаковые ли массивы, а мне нужно знать процент совпадения. Если бы массивы были одной размерности, то подсчитал количество одинаковых элементов и успокоился. А в данном случае еще нужно определиться, а недостающее количество элементов в одном из массивов куда записывать? В несовпадающие элементы или пренебречь?

Comment: Вот и мне интересно, что за процент совпадений?

Comment: и сравнивать больший с меньшим массивом или наоборот?

Comment: Чисто теоретически. Единицей сравнения является элемент массива.Если есть массив, то можно сравнить либо элементы, либо вектор массива.  Для элементов посчитать количество совпадений в другом массиве общее или уникальное. Либо количество совпавших векторов. Сравнить поэлементно, либо преобразовать массив в строку и найти вхождение.. Вряд ли что-то еще можно придумать

Comment: заголовок не очень. куча вариантов. мало инфы. предложите алгоритм. или вы тут его хотите получить?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы поймете лучше прочитав тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/115147/ (MinHash — выявляем похожие множества). И в догонку http://ru-delphi.livejournal.com/269773.html

Comment: @Vlad Chapl? спасибо. Алгоритм Жаккара - это то, что нужно.

Comment: Поиграв с алгоритмами из Википедии, а также из статей Хабра, я увидел, что народ взял за основу **коэффициент Жаккарда** или **индекс Маарела** и т.п. Но это все хорошо для множеств с уникальными элементами, а  для определения похожести текстов, использую шинглы, можно использовать эти алгоритмы с большой осторожностью. **Очень сильно** результат зависит от размера шингла. Иногда выдается результат в 220% или 146% впрочем как и наш изберком))

Comment: Поэтому нужно сравнивать не элементы массивов, а **сами шинглы** или в нашем случая строки массива!!!

Answer (score 1):

*В коментарии не дало написать, пишу в ответе.*

MinHash неплохо ложится на БД (в частности SQLite). Там для каждого текста вычисляется вектор хэшей. Для нового текста вычисляется такой же вектор. Потом тупо смотрится **поэлеметное** совпадение двух векторов. Т.е. hash1[i]=hashNew[i]. Если у нас из 100 хэшей совпало 55, то считаем совпадение 55% (и никаких  "220%"!).

Еще раз: размерность вектора всегда одинаковая и не зависит от размера текста, задается на этапе проектирования. Для размера вектора 100 хэшей идет 100 сравнений. Считается число совпадений - много совпадений, значит тексты одинаковые.

Про то как считаются и отбираются хэши читай на хабре (вроде понятно). Я этот алгоритм у себя внедрял (большой хэш http://ru-delphi.livejournal.com/269773.html нарезал на кусочки), вроде работает. Важный комментарий: чем больше вектор хэшей, тем точнее идет сравнение, но и нагрузка на БД возрастает. У меня размер вектора порядка 220, но, видимо, можно было бы и больше. В моей задаче использую связку алгоритмов. На первом этапе быстро отбираю несколько десятков кандидатов, а потом более медленным и точным алгоритмом нахожу среди них нужного (лучшего).

Если нужно альтернативы, то смотри тут http://lit999.narod.ru/soft/string.html один из вариантов (на самом деле там два варианта, для одного из них есть тест http://lit999.narod.ru/soft/string_similar/test.html).

Comment: Я видел эти статьи, и вот я чего не понимаю. Почему то все гонятся за хэш-функциями и каждый изгаляется как может в их применении. Как я понимаю, хэш-функция нужна только для того, чтобы получить из строки  число, а числа сравнивать намного быстрее, чем строки. А так как самое простое при сравнении двух текстов - это сравнить количество одинаковых слов, то используя хэш - это просто ускорить сравнение. Но набор слов не говорит о плагиате или не очень говорит об этом. Поэтому и придумали шинглы. Я могу сильно ошибаться и не видеть простого.

Comment: Хэши не только быстрее. Например у вас по 10 шинглов (а слова это частный случай шинглов). По наивному вам нужно 100 сравнений. MinHash алгоритм позволяет провести 10 сравнений и даже меньше (за счет потери точности, разумеется). На больших текстах выигрыш ещё больше (там уже тысячекратное ускорение может быть). К тому же MinHash удобно использовать в связке с БД.